# Material design input show error

Tags: angular, material-design

I am using material design lite in angular2.

I marked an input field as required like:

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input"
                       type="text"
                       id="user"
                       [(ngModel)]="login.user"
                       ngControl="user"
                       #user="ngForm"
                       (blur)="onBlur()"
                       required
                       />
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="user">User</label>
                <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Field is required.</span>
            </div>
```

But when I just load the page, it shows error message even, I haven't touch the field.
[image]

How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

**`!user.valid`**  says user should be required (valid).
**`!user.pristine`** tells that endUser should touch the input field then error msg will be show.

```
<span [class.mdl-textfield__error]="!user.valid && !user.pristine" 
      *ngIf="!user.valid && !user.pristine">Field is required.
</span>
```

If you don't want to use **`pristine`**, simply remove other condition.

Comment: It does not work as expected, because the input field is still red.

Comment: It does not work as expected. When I leave the input field with empty value, then it will not marked as red.